# priority vs. privilege

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

This is from [a webpage](https://www.goodgoodgood.co/articles/bad-news-quotes).

> “The brains of humans contain a mechanism that is designed to give
> **priority** to bad news.” — Daniel Kahneman

I am curious whether '**priority**' could be replaced with '*privilege*' here.

According to Oxford Learner's Dictionaries, '**priority**' is defined as 'the most important place among various things that have to be done' and 'privilege', as 'a special right or advantage that a particular person or group of people has'.

I can't tell the difference even after looking them up in the dictionary.

Comment: The meanings of "priority" and "privilege" are rather different.  Is there a particular dictionary definition you are thinking of?

Comment: @JamesK No, I just read that 'priority' is one of the synonyms of 'privilege' on a webpage. (https://www.thesaurus.net/privilege)

Comment: Okay, go check a dictionary, and report back.

Comment: @JamesK Okay, I checked a dictionary and edited the OP.

Comment: Synonyms are not always usable as replacements, because they usually have different nuances. Words also often have multiple meanings, and the synonym only applies to some of them.

Comment: There are very few absolutely strict synonyms (meaning that you could always replace one with another, regardless of context). So webpages that list synonyms *usually* are doing so with a looser criteria; words with similar enough meanings that some sentences using the word could be reworded to use a "synonym" and convey a similar meaning. Generally you have to know both words reasonably well to know if such a replacement would be helpful in your context. Thesauruses are useful for reminding you of words you already know but haven't thought of. Not for giving you *new* information about words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per your definition, a privilege is  special right that a *person* has.  It is normally countable:

> As a member of the club you have several privileges.  You can use the club bar and may vote in club meetings.

It would be odd to talk about a privilege held by a thing such as a news report.

"Priority" on the other hand is just about ordering: putting the more important items in front of the less important. In this sense it is non-count, and "give priority to" is a common colocation, as is "take priority".

> Schools shouldn't give priority to maths over music and art, as creative skills are more important in the modern workplace.

For these reasons, priority could not be replaced by privilege in this context.

It is possible to use privilege as a verb.  In the verbal sense it is similar to "prioritize"

> They do not privilege/prioritize one approach over the other.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but I don't think it's odd or unusual to talk about privileges for an element inside a system. I also think it is possible to use "priority" as a numeric value; ie, instead of saying "give priority to A over B" you could say "give higher priority to A".

Answer (score 4):

These are not interchangeable in this respect.

Consider that 'priority' puts you at the head of a queue [line] & that 'privilege' is being allowed in the queue at all.

In this way, you can think of 'privilege' as being more akin to 'permission'. It's a permission not afforded to all.

That leaves you to consider that priority, amongst those with the necessary privilege, is to be ahead of others with equal permission.

> Only business class passengers have the privilege of using the fast check-in. Those who have also purchased priority passes should come to the head of the queue.

Comment: Note that the verbs "prioritize" and "privilege" are reasonably considered to be synonyms. "To privilege" implies ordering more so than acceptance (you are correct that the noun "privilege" refers to the acceptance of something, not its order).